# spsample error: "proj4string for signature null" even though proj4string is not null

Tags: r, r-sp

After running this series I get an error from the spsample function telling me "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string’ for signature ‘"NULL"’" However, given the code above the spsample function and running proj4string(SLDF) and getting a non null result I am really confused. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

```
SLDF <- spTransform(SLDF, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=8 +datum=WGS84"))
proj4string(SLDF)
test <- spsample(SLDF, n = 1000, type = "stratified", cellsize = c(1500,1500))
```

Comment: you have a typo (SLFD instead than SLDF ) in the third line.

Comment: thanks, but that should not change the question at hand.

Comment: Did you try it ? because the error seems to be related to passing a `NULL` variable to `spsample`

Comment: Yes, same result. Here I am using SLDF as placeholders, my actual data have different names. And I checked my spelling.

Comment: please produce a reproducible example.